# Java regex not capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I am applying a regex to the following string:

**2x#0$×4x#3$÷5x#0$**

using the following code:

```
String monomialRegex = "(-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[x][#]-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[\\$])";
String string2 = "2x#0$×4x#3$÷5x#0$";//the × between $ and 4 is a times symbol
string2 = string2.replaceAll(monomialRegex+"([×])"+monomialRegex+"([÷])"+monomialRegex,"÷$1%$5@×$3");
```

my result is coming out as: **÷2x#0$%4x#3$@×**

From what I understand about groups:

```
$1 = 2x#0$
$2 = ×
$3 = 4x#3$
$4 = ÷
$5 = 5x#0$
```

in the result, I see that instead of using group $5 it uses group $3 AND
group $3 does not even appear?

Any advice as to how to handle this regex expression?

Comment: so can you tell me which are three groups?? $1 = ? $2 = ? $3 = ? @Aaron and

Comment: no decimal.. but in the regex monomialRegex the decimal part is optional @Aaron

Comment: Sure, this is why you match even though the decimal capturing groups do not match anything

Comment: What about "×"  and "÷"  wouldn't they be considered groups, as well. @Aaron

Comment: Wait, I did have misunderstood your regex (it's not the one on the first line, you craft a regex based on it in the third line). I'll try to write a comprehensive answer rather than comment.

Comment: I think the problem is the sub group: (\\.\\d*)? WITHIN monomialRegex...I'll eliminate the subgroups and it should work. @Aaron

Comment: The problem is how the groups are called out... I need to know how to call out all the groups within the regex.. including the SUB-GROUPS of "monomialRegex". I just tested it without the subgroups of "monomialRegex" AND it works @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Your full regex is :

```
(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])([×])(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])([÷])(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])
```

Its capturing groups are :

1. `(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])`
2. `(\.\d*)`
3. `(\.\d*)`
4. `([×])`
5. `(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])`
6. `(\.\d*)`
7. `(\.\d*)`
8. `([÷])`
9. `(-?\d+(\.\d*)?[x][#]-?\d+(\.\d*)?[\$])`
10. `(\.\d*)`
11. `(\.\d*)`

With your current input, the following groups have content :

- 1 : 2x#0$
- 4 : ×
- 5 : 4x#3$
- 8 : ÷
- 9 : 5x#0$

You can visualize that on regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/Nh0xxW/1

I would use the following to accomplish the same goal (at least if I've guessed it correctly) :

```
Match (-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?x#-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?\$)×(-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?x#-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?\$)÷(-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?x#-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?\$)
Replace by %$1%$2@×$3
```

As seen here : https://regex101.com/r/Nh0xxW/2

I mainly simplified the regex by removing useless groups (no need to capture decimals which are part of the whole monomial capturing group nor ÷ and × which you don't use in the replacement) and single-character character classes.

You can still craft the regex with concatenation of a more simple one if you want (although I find it makes the whole thing more complex to understand in the end), and the following code will do so :

```
String monomialRegex = "(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?x#-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?\\$)";
String completeRegex = monomialRegex + "×" + monomialRegex + "÷" + monomialRegex;
```

I've tested the java code on ideone : https://ideone.com/Eg8Zz6

Comment: Okay Aaron I will test your regex out soon... thanks for the information @Aaron

Comment: @i_o I added Java code with the original regex decomposition (which I would like to discourage)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the sub-groups inside monomialRegex:

I got rid of the subgroup: (\.\d*)? within monomialRegex.

I replaced this subgroup with [\.]?[\d+]? and it works. 
I did not need to change the ordering of the groups within the entire regex.

Comment: Why `[\.]?[\d+]?`? Why not `\.?\d*`? Better yet, why not `(?:\.\d*)?`, i.e. changing the capturing group to a **non**-capturing group, so it doesn't even try to process the `\d` unless it found a `\.` first (i.e. better performance)?

Comment: can you explain (?:\.\d*)? Also, I did use [\.]?[\d+]? because I don't have to change the ordering of groups.. group 1 is still $1 and group 3 is still $3, likewise for groups, 2, 4 and any other groups that the replaceAll function calls makes. @Andreas

Comment: I already explained `(?:xxx)`. It is a [**non-capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).